# Why innerHTML properity cannot get the wanted value

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

In w3schools Javascript tutorial it states: 
The value of the text node can be accessed by the node's innerHTML property, or the nodeValue.

Then I change the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="intro">Hello World!</p>

<script>
txt=document.getElementById("intro").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
document.write(txt);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="intro">Hello World!</p>

<script>
txt=document.getElementById("intro").childNodes[0].innerHTML;
document.write(txt);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't work, could anyone please let me know did I miss something here? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use w3schools ! --> http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.getElementById("intro").childNodes[0]` is a *text node*, but only element nodes have `innerHTML`.

You can use `document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML` instead (to get the `innerHTML` of the paragraph instead of of the text inside the paragraph).

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
txt=document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;
document.write(txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access `innerHTML` directly from the `p` element:

```
txt=document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;
document.write(txt);
```

Also, try to find an alternative to W3Schools: http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
txt=document.getElementById("intro").childNodes[0].innerHTML;
```

To

```
txt=document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/THMVC/

Answer (score 0):

use only

```
txt=document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML;
```